# calling a shell script AFTER data is inserted into a table in sybase

Tags: triggers, insert, sybase, sap-ase, xp-cmdshell

I would like to call a shell script AFTER data is inserted into a table (say A) in Sybase 12.5.4.

If I use a trigger, on the table A and call xp_cmdshell, then the shell script woudl get called before the insert (data is inserted after the trigger exec completes).

Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Puttion some logic in the shell script to login to the database and check for the records in question would be one option.  Another you may want to look at would be using an intermediary table.  Insert TABLE A -> Trigger A writes to Table B -> Trigger B executes shell script.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty I would poll the table from the shell script not push from the database - xp_cmdshell is rarely the best option and a potential security hazard.